# Cambiar color de un boton al pulsarlo

Tags: android-studio, xml

Estoy intentando hacer que se cambie de color un Button al presionarlo pero no hay manera 
activity_xml:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

drawable:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añade el código a la publicación y no en fotos, para que se pueda copiar y poder así hacer pruebas.

Comment: [Las capturas de código no son de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)

Comment: Hola Mihai, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Ésta es una pregunta interesante pero, como comentan otros usuarios, la deberías [edit] para cambiar las imágenes por el código en sí. Lee [ask] y [¿Cómo darle formato a mis publicaciones utilizando Markdown o HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) para más información y consejos.

Answer (score 2):

La propiedad `checked` solo puede ser usada a checkbox o radiobuttons la forma que podrías usar es la de `state_` para utilizar en el botón para cambiar de color según el estado.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/red"/> <!-- presionado -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/blue"/> <!-- en foco -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/black"/> <!-- por defecto -->
</selector>
```

Usa el selector como `background`:

```
android:background="@drawable/butonpulsado"
```

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias

Comment: @MihaiMinca si la solución propuesta en esta respuesta hizo que el problema se resolviera, deberías marcarla como aceptada pulsando en el ✔ que hay en la parte izquierda de la respuesta.